# Show different result based on output redirect

Tags: shell, stdout

For exmaple, the `mysql` command

```
mysql -e 'show databases'

+--------------------------+
| Database                 |
+--------------------------+
| information_schema       |
| mysql                    |
| performance_schema       |
+--------------------------+
```

But when you redirect to a file, the content is different, e.g.

```
mysql -e 'show databases' > /tmp/test.txt
cat /tmp/test.txt

Database
mysql
performance_schema
```

Comment: Whats the question? Are you asking why its different? Or how to do this sort of thing in your own script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done by checking if STDOUT is connected to a TTY using the [`isatty()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty) call (in C, substitute the equivalent for your language of choice).

Comment: I think you want `STDOUT_FILENO` here, not `STDOUT`. Also, this only works for POSIX; for Win32, you can do `_isatty(_fileno(stdout))` instead; for other platforms… let's hope nobody cares.

Answer (score 2):

For Python, you can use `sys.stdout.isatty()`.

**`test.py`**:

```
import sys

if sys.stdout.isatty():
    print 'Yep'
else:
    print 'Nope'
```

And a demo:

```
$ python2 test.py                                         
Yep
$ python2 test.py | cat
Nope
$ python2 test.py > test.txt
$ cat test.txt
Nope
```

Comment: `mysql` seems to do this on (at least) Windows as well as *nix. Isn't Python's `file.isatty()` Unix-only? Or does it do something magic instead of `os.isatty(self.fileno())` on Windows, so it's cross-platform?

Comment: @abarnert: I don't have Windows installed so I can't test it, but it seems like `isatty()` is Unix-only.

Comment: That's what I was worried about. There is a Windows equivalent in C, which you could always wrap with `ctypes` out of (I think) `MSVCRT.DLL` if worst comes to worst, but that's not quite as simple as the OP was probably hoping for…